# Find the matrix representation of T in the basis B

Tags: linear-algebra

In $P_2$ the space of polynomials at most two, the ordered bases is we use is $E=\{x^2,x,1\}$. There is another basis for this space, $B= \{x^2-1,x+1,x-1\}$.

a)Find the change of basis matrix from B to E:

So I got = $\begin{bmatrix}1 &0 & 0\\0 &1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$

b) Find the change of basis matrix from $E$ to $B$. So for this I need to find the inverse of a $3\times3$ matrix, correct?

I started with: 
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 &0 &1 & 0\\ -1& 1&1 & 0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}$ and then I got.... $\begin{bmatrix}1 &0 & 0 &1 &0 &0\\0 &1 &1 &0 &1 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-1 &1 \end{bmatrix}$

Is everything to the right of the $0$'s on the third row the inverse?

Finally how would I go about writing the polynomial $2x^2+4x +4$ in the basis $b$ would it just be $\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\4\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: on first line I think  you mean ordered basis. The standard basis is technically $\{1,x,x^2\}$ NOT $\{x^2,x,1\}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $[I]^E_B =Q$. The interplay bw transformation matrix on your "Ordered basis" is

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \\  [T]^{E}_{E} &=[I]^E_B [T]^B_B [I]^B_E 
\\ [T]_E&=[I]^E_B [T]_B [I]^B_E 
\\ Q^{-1}[T]_E Q&=[T]_B
\end{aligned}$$
just to make sure $Q=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0&0 \\ 0&1&1 \\-1&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$
and $Q^{-1}$ is the inverse of it

[image]